# How would we find a suitable function that approximately fits the data from a table or graph?

Tags: probability, functions

I have a Histogram that's like this:

[image]

How would I find a suitable function that approximately fits the data? I think that I would need to use Geogebra, or a similar program.

The exact data of the table is the following:

```
10 - 15 : 0.123
16 - 21 : 0.509
22 - 27 : 0.246
28 - 33 : 0.105
34 - 39 : 0.017
```

Comment: You have five midpoint x's and five corresponding y's so you can always define a 5-degree polynomial that fits the data and solve for the five linear equations.

Comment: @cr001 do you mean midpoint as in the middle point when you say 5 midpoint x's?

Comment: Yes, for example the first $x$ point would be $12.5$